# Send file from Android to Servlet via HttpConnection POST

Tags: android, servlets, post, send, httpconnection

I have this code on my android:

```
try {
    http = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://35.9.22.102:8080/Services/SubmitMedia/");
    http.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    http.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", file.length + "");

    dos = http.openDataOutputStream();
    dos.write(file);

    int response = ((HttpConnection) http).getResponseCode();
    if (response == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) System.out.println("Success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally   {
    try {
        if (http != null) http.close();
        if (dos != null) dos.close();
    } catch (Exception e)   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code for the servlet side:

```
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());  
byte[] data = new byte[0];  
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];  
int bytesRead;  
while ((bytesRead = din.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {  
    // construct large enough array for all the data we now have  
    byte[] newData = new byte[data.length + bytesRead];  
    // copy data previously read  
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);  
    // append data newly read  
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newData, data.length, bytesRead);  
    // discard the old array in favour of the new one  
    data = newData;  
}
```

The problem is the code broke when it reaches `Connector.open("http://35.9.22.102:8080/Services/SubmitMedia/")` on the Android part. The program skips whole thing and goes to `finally`. I am not sure what would be the main problem in here. I need some help.

Comment: Absolutely nothing in the stacktrace?